# Creating a file through cmd with java

Tags: java, readfile

I am running `java "Program" file1.txt < file2.txt`

and I get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

`String filename = args[0];` this is where the error occurs.

This is probably a really simple question, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What do you intend `java "Program" < file.txt` to do? Why do you expect that?

Comment: I want it to take in the inputs from file.txt

Comment: Remove `<` and it should work. And, always check `args.length` first.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your program is written in `Program.java` you can directly pass argument in main method as `java Program file.txt`where args[0] will be `"file.txt"`